# pg:pull, pg:backups no longer available in heroku cli

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-cli

Just strange, I am doing back database maintenance, I tried to to a `heroku pg:pull <DB_URL> local_db --app <appname>` and it says:

> pg:pull is not a heroku command.

I tried to create a backup with `heroku pg:backups:capture <DB_URL>` and i get this:

> pg:backups:capture is not a heroku command.

Just trying `heroku pg:backups` shows:

> pg:backups is not a heroku command.

Its strange because even in the --help section, looks like all the useful commands are gone:

```
heroku pg --help
Usage: heroku pg [DATABASE]

 -a, --app APP       # app to run command against
 -r, --remote REMOTE # git remote of app to run command against

Commands for pg, type "heroku help pg:COMMAND" for more details:

 heroku pg [DATABASE]                  # 
 heroku pg:info [DATABASE]             # 
 heroku pg:wait [DATABASE]             #
```

I looked around online and didn't see anything about these `pg` command deprications.  I checked my heroku CLI version: `heroku-cli/5.3.0-5329fb8 (darwin-amd64) go1.6.2`

Strange becuase I've been using these commands on this same computer many times recently and suddenly they're gone.

Have these `pg` been depricated (I doubt)?  If not does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  If so, anyone know how to do push/pull/capture in the new framework?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that my CLI version was out-of-date.  I followed [these instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#uninstalling-the-heroku-cli) on my Mac:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/heroku
rm -rf ~/.local/share/heroku ~/.config/heroku ~/.cache/heroku
```

And then re-installed using homebrew:

```
brew update
brew install heroku
```

Apparently the new version of the CLI is supposed to keep itself up-to-date.